# Is there options how to code/create workflow using SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workflow, spfx, sharepointframework

I developing web-part client-side solution using sharepoint framework. I successfully create a lists with some columns (it's list's columns not site). But now, I need to create a workflow, so is there any options, how to coding workflows using sharepoint framework and web-part client side solution? Have anybody some ideas or documentations witch could help me to moved further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't create workflow in SPFx solution, you could use SharePoint add-in or Microsoft flow.

SharePoint add-in solution samples:

https://www.vrdmn.com/2014/09/integrated-workflow-apps-deploy.html

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Workflow.AssociateToHostWeb